# Jquery focus() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have called a JQuery function in onblur event and  in that function I used `focus()`.
But, the `JQuery focus()` is not working.

```
<input type="text" name="stdmeas['XXL']" id="XXL_qty" value="<?php echo $XXL;?>" size="5" onblur="return fnqtyCount();" />

function fnqtyCount() {
   if(!$.isNumeric( XXL_qty )) {
        $("#err_msg").text("Please enter the numeric values only.");
        $("#XXL_qty").val('');
        $("#XXL_qty").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the handler using `.focus` (or `.on()`, which I believe is the new way)? Does the event not trigger at all, or is it your function which is not working?

Answer (score 3):

as per my understanding , the code should be as follows

```
function fnqtyCount() {
   if(!$.isNumeric( $("#XXL_qty").val() )) {
        $("#err_msg").text("Please enter the numeric values only.");
        $("#XXL_qty").val('');
        $("#XXL_qty").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: any specific error in the console (e.g. Firebug console) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function fnqtyCount() {
      var text = $("#XXL_qty").val();
      if (!$.isNumeric(text)) {
          $("#err_msg").text("Please enter the numeric values only.");
          $("#XXL_qty").val('');
          $("#XXL_qty").focus();
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: It is working fine and the I have the latest version of the same. Firefox 29.0